# Ruby Reference & Value pass by

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked. I've read them, and still don't understand WHY my code does what it does. It s only for training, and I've implement a simple LinkedList (single link) and I wanted to implement the merge of two such sorted list. Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#
module LinkedList

    class Node

        attr_accessor :next,:data

        def to_s
            s = @data.to_s + " -> "
            s += @next.to_s if @next
            s
        end
    end

end
def append tail, node
    tail.next = node
    tail = node
    node = node.next
end

def merge_lists2 list1, list2
    tail = LinkedList::Node.new
    while(list1 && list2)
        list1.data <= list2.data ? list1 = append(tail,list1) : list2 = append(tail,list2)
        puts list1
        puts list2
        puts tail
        puts "#######################################################"
        STDIN.gets
    end
    if list1
        tail.next = list1
    elsif list2
        tail.next = list2
    end
    tail.next
end
def generateList times = 3,factor = 1
    list = LinkedList::Node.new
    list.data = 0
    curr = list
    (1..times).each do |i|
        curr.next = LinkedList::Node.new
        curr = curr.next
        curr.data = i*factor
    end
    list
end

def main
    l1 = generateList 4,2
    l2 = generateList 5,1.5
    puts l1
    puts l2
    l3 = merge_lists2 l1,l2
    puts l3
end
```

The code following is my "older" version :

```
def append tail, node
    tail.next = node
    tail = node
    node = node.next
end

def merge_lists2 list1, list2
    tail = LinkedList::Node.new
    while(list1 && list2)
        list1.data <= list2.data ? append(tail,list1) : append(tail,list2)
```

In the older version, it was running in a infinite loop because list1 and list2 were never updated, thus the while loop was always going on. They were never updated because of the list1 & list2 variable were assigned to different object in the append function, thus when returning from the function, list1 and list2 were "taking back" on their original reference.
But the "tail" reference is updated !! You can see it by running the code, you will see that tail is always the "tail" of the new merged list, and not the "head" of the new list. I dont understand why because tail is ALSO referenced to a new object in append, so when returning from the function, "tail" should still be the "head" (lol that's crazy )

Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Ruby is it hides a lot of things from you. Objects are passed in as what appear to be references, but are actually pointers in a clever disguise. When you "de-reference" a pointer you get to manipulate the original data, not unlike a reference. Unlike C++ where this is made explicit, Ruby doesn't go out of its way to remind you this is the case.

So what this means is arguments to methods are simply variables that behave like pointers to objects. Changing them to other values does not affect the original. Calling methods on them or changing properties does affect the original, they've been de-referenced.

There's a lot of problems with your implementation here. For one, methods like `append` should be part of the Node class:

```
class Node
  def append(list)
    node = @data

    while (node)
      if (node.next)
        node = node.next
      else
        node.next = list
        return self
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So long as you don't have a circular list, that should work. Notice that the `list` value is never modified, it's simply integrated.

Note that this `append` method works for both individual nodes (one element lists) and longer lists composed of multiple nodes. Generally in programming you try to avoid having exceptional cases to handle, so this minimizes the code you need to write and get working properly.

Comment: ...this is the same behavior in Java, C# etc. In some languages you can _explicitly_ say you want to pass by reference (using `ref String myVar` for example), but by default, you pass pointers to the values, which means that setting them (rather than manipulating them) does not change the values for the caller

Comment: I know in a regular good implementation append should be part of the Node class. However, that is not what i want ;) Because what I want is my "tail" variable, to always point to the head of the new list (to print it after) ! If I were to use your code, tail would always point to the TAIL of the list. And your explanation does not answer WHY the tail varaible points to different object each time I call my function "append"  ... (since i make tail pointing to different object in the function, the caller should not see the difference .. but it does !!)

Comment: Changing local variables has no effect outside of that block. For anything to be permanent you need to manipulate either a) the property of an object passed in (e.g. `tail.next`), or b) a local or class level `@` type instance variable (e.g `@tail`). Your attempt to reassign `tail` and have it back-propagate will not work. Instead, try retooling the example I've given here to have the behaviour you want.

Comment: So in my function append, the "tail" variable is updated (in the caller) because i do "tail.next = node" ?  I thought because of the "tail = node" in the function, the "tail" variable would be left untouched in the caller.